# Docker Compose with MacOS Docker Desktop watch for changes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using docker desktop to debug .net core api application and it works but the watch for changes not working.

Any ideas?

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Microservices/Customer/MyAccounts.Customer.API/MyAccounts.Customer.API.csproj", "Microservices/Customer/MyAccounts.Customer.API/"]
COPY ["Microservices/Customer/MyAccounts.Customer.Domain/MyAccounts.Customer.Domain.csproj", "Microservices/Customer/MyAccounts.Customer.Domain/"]
COPY ["Core/MyAccounts.Core/MyAccounts.Core.csproj", "Core/MyAccounts.Core/"]
COPY ["Microservices/Customer/MyAccounts.Customer.Data/MyAccounts.Customer.Data.csproj", "Microservices/Customer/MyAccounts.Customer.Data/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Microservices/Customer/MyAccounts.Customer.API/MyAccounts.Customer.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Microservices/Customer/MyAccounts.Customer.API"
RUN dotnet build "MyAccounts.Customer.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyAccounts.Customer.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAccounts.Customer.API.dll"]
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myaccounts.customer.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myaccountscustomer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Microservices/Customer/MyAccounts.Customer.API/Dockerfile
    volumes:
       - /Microservices/Customer/MyAccounts.Customer.API:/app
```

**docker-compose.override**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myaccounts.customer.api:
    environment:
      - DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000;
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    entrypoint: "dotnet watch run --urls=http://+:5000"
```

Comment: Which command do you use to debug your program?

Comment: From Visual Studio for Mac `docker-compose.dcproj`

Comment: And this is the command being executed by `docker-compose.dcproj` debug `Starting: "docker" exec -i b07a818d4ffd /bin/sh -c "ID=.; if [ -e /etc/os-release ]; then . /etc/os-release; fi; if [ $ID = alpine ] && [ -e /remote_debugger/linux-musl-x64/vsdbg ]; then VSDBGPATH=/remote_debugger/linux-musl-x64; else VSDBGPATH=/remote_debugger; fi; $VSDBGPATH/vsdbg --interpreter=vscode --interpreter=vscode"
-------`